# Using Atom with Stack (Haskell) - How to interactively evaluate from within IDE

Tags: haskell, ide, atom-editor

I am new to Atom / Stack / Haskell and after a fair bit of hand wringing managed to get set up on my windows 10 box.

One thing I am still stumped on is finding a way to set up interactive evaluation from within Atom (like "debugging" in Leksah)?

I have installed the "Script" which looks promising but all I get is:

```
'ghc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I presume I need some kind of configuration but I can't work out what's required. I think need a way to pipe through to an open ghci console.

Is there a way of setting this up with "Script"or any similar package?

Thanks

John

Comment: are you looking for a *REPL*? AFAIK it's in https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell-repl - but it probably lacks stack support - so I guess just open a terminal/command-prompt and do `stack repl` in your projects folder

Comment: Yep there it is right in front of me - that's correct thanks @Carsten - and it works with stack . Feel free to make this an answer if not I'll copy it into an answer next week sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you checked for yourself the [ide-haskell-repl](https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell-repl) *atom-package* should work here